# How to change the size of mat-card in angular material

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material, grid

[image: Screenshot]

I want both Components the same height (the size of left form) tried margin , padding nothing works

below is the code for its parent element HTML

```
<mat-tab label="Update Profile">

    <div class="container">
      <mat-card class="mat-card-container">
      <div class="vertical-center row" >

        <div class="col-lg-1">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <app-register [user]="user"></app-register>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 password-change-form">
          <app-password-change [id]="user.id"></app-password-change>
        </div>



        <div class="col-lg-1">
        </div>

      </div>
      </mat-card>
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
```

CSS

```
.vertical-center {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.password-change-form{
  padding: inherit;
}
.spacer{}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better you can use `flex layout`. Refer: `[https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxLayoutAlign-API][1]`

Set `fxFlexAlign="stretch"` to have all mat-card in same height.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. There's even one only demo where you can simulate the parameters of the Angular Flex Layout: https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the mat card, but with the div with password-change-form if you were asking to make them the same height:

```
.password-change-form{
   height:100%
}
```

but if you want them to have the same width, you should probably add col-lg-5 to both of them instead of 6 and 4

```
    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <app-register [user]="user"></app-register>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-5 password-change-form">
      <app-password-change [id]="user.id"></app-password-change>
    </div>
```

Comment: same height and your solution doesn’t work but thank you

Comment: is the mat card inside the app-password-change component?

Comment: if yes try this put this inside the css file of the component `mat-card {
  width: calc(100% - 70px);
  height: calc(100% - 70px);
}`